# Few people see "Apache Test page", others see website

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have a simple WordPress website that seems to work properly, however, some people see the default Apache test page when they visit the site. This is only a small percentage of the people that have visited the page.

Never had this issue before, and was hoping anyone knows what could be this issue.

Comment: Check the site with and without the 'www'. If that's the problem just set it in the config of the Apache.

Comment: I have tried that and isn't the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Might be a dns problem. Did you move your website to a new server recently?